# Integer SIMD Instruction AVX in C

Tags: c, gcc, simd, avx

I am trying to run SIMD instruction over data types `int`, `float` and `double`.
I need multiply, add and load operation.

For `float` and `double` I successfully managed to make those instructions work:

`_mm256_add_ps`, `_mm256_mul_ps` and `_mm256_load_ps` (ending *pd for double).
(Direct FMADD operation isn't supported)

But for integer I couldn't find a working instruction. All of those showed at intel AVX manual give similar error by GCC 4.7 like "‘_mm256_mul_epu32’ was not declared in this scope".

For loading integer I use `_mm256_set_epi32` and that's fine for GCC. I don't know why those other instructions aren't defined. Do I need to update something?

I am including all of those `<pmmintrin.h>, <immintrin.h> <x86intrin.h>`

My processor is an Intel core i5 3570k (Ivy Bridge).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

256-bit integer operations are only added since AVX2, so you'll have to use 128-bit `__m128i` vectors for integer intrinsics if you only have AVX1.

AVX1 does have integer loads/stores, and intrinsics like `_mm256_set_epi32` can be implemented with FP shuffles or a simple load of a compile-time constant.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions#Advanced_Vector_Extensions_2

> Advanced Vector Extensions 2 (AVX2), also known as Haswell New Instructions,[2] is an expansion of the AVX instruction set introduced in Intel's Haswell microarchitecture. AVX2 makes the following additions:
>
> - expansion of most vector integer SSE and AVX instructions to 256 bits
> - three-operand general-purpose bit manipulation and multiply
> - three-operand fused multiply-accumulate support (FMA3)
> - Gather support, enabling vector elements to be loaded from non-contiguous memory locations
> - DWORD- and QWORD-granularity any-to-any permutes
> - vector shifts.

FMA3 is actually a separate feature; AMD Piledriver/Steamroller have it but not AVX2.

Nevertheless if the int value range fits in 24 bits then you can use `float` instead. However note that if you need the *exact result* or the *low bits of the result* then you'll have to convert `float` to `double`, because a 24x24 multiplication will produce a 48-bit result which can be only stored exactly in a `double`.  At that point you still only have 4 elements per vector, and might have been better off with XMM vectors of `int32`.  (But note that FMA throughput is typically better than integer multiply throughput.)

AVX1 has VEX encodings of 128-bit integer operations so you can use them in the same function as 256-bit FP intrinsics without causing SSE-AVX transition stalls.  (In C you generally don't have to worry about that; your compiler will take care of using `vzeroupper` where needed.)

You could try to simulate an integer addition with AVX bitwise instructions like VANDPS and VXORPS, but without a bitwise left shift for ymm vectors it won't work.

If you're sure FTZ / DAZ are not set, you can use small integers *as* denormal / subnormal `float` values, where the bits outside the mantissa are all zero.  Then FP addition and integer addition are the same bitwise operation.  (And VADDPS doesn't need a microcode assist on Intel hardware when the inputs and result are both denormal.)

Comment: Addition [needs the carry-out left shifted by 1 bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9070937/adding-two-numbers-without-operator-clarification), so even with a LOT of VANDPS and VXORPS YMM instructions can can't simulate `vpaddb`.